# Debug Future async flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to test output of this function ... how i can debug this using inspect or print ?

```
  Future<YourDataEntity> getproduct(int id) async {
    var response = await Network().getData('/publication/show/$id');
       return YourDataEntity.fromJson(response.body['publication']);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just assigning the output to a temporary variable?

```dart
import 'dart:developer';

Future<YourDataEntity> getproduct(int id) async {
  var response = await Network().getData('/publication/show/$id');
  final entity = YourDataEntity.fromJson(response.body['publication']);
  log(entity.toString())
  return entity;
}
```

But the most *correct* way is to use a debugger and add a breakpoint where you call this function.

There's a great video that teaches you just that:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ocvQ2aMluq8

Comment: final entity = YourDataEntity.fromJson(response.body['publication']);
  print(entity) didn't display anything ... how i fix that ?

Comment: I've updated the answer with `log`, could you try that one out?

Comment: The argument type 'YourDataEntity' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Comment: You have to call `.toString()` on the entity. I've updated the answer